# How to decode json data array

Tags: php, json

My php script below:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "college";
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
$query = "SELECT firstname, secondname, pic FROM student";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$response = array();
While($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
array_push($response,array('fname'=>$row[0], 'sname'=>$row[1], 'pic'=>$row[2]));
}
mysqli_close($con);
echo json_encode(array('server_response'=>$response));
?>
```

Outputs:

```
{"server_response":[{" fname":"john","sname":"mark","pic":"http:\/\/localhost\/ServerSide\/jm.jpg"}]}
```

How can I decode the JSON data to have an output with a proper url as below:

```
{"server_response":[{" fname":"john","sname":"mark","pic":"http://localhost/ServerSide/jm.jpg"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to just replace those strings:

```
echo str_replace('\/','/',json_encode(array('response'=>$response)));
```

Or perhaps try [strip slashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

The other alternative is to encode with this argument but requires php 5.4 or higher.

```
echo json_encode(array('response'=>$response),JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```